# Liquidsoap Recording Over All Files In Output Folder

Tags: linux, icecast, internet-radio, liquidsoap

So I have an instance of Liquidsoap, with a harbor input on port 8080.

What I'd like to have happen is whenever someone connects to /live, the stream is recorded and saved on a server.

This works fine, however, if for example I am recording, then disconnect and allow the playlist to kick in, when I try and stream again, it creates a new file, but starts writing to both the new file and the previous recording.

It is basically over writing the first file. The only way this doesn't happen, is if liquidsoap has a restart between the 2 broadcasts.

Here is a copy of my liq file:

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap

# Don't create a pidfile
#set("init.daemon.pidfile",false)

# Create Log File
set("log.file.path","/tmp/ls-log.log")
set("log.file.perms",755)
set("log.unix_timestamps",true)

# DJ or Metadata IP Address
set("harbor.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")

# Port / Pass for Live DJs
live = input.harbor(id="live",port=8080,password="xxxxxx", "live")

# Find /home/music/ -type f -name "*.mp3" > /etc/liquidsoap/music.m3u

# Path to playlist file which contains a list of local mp3's (/home/user/mp3/song.mp3)
playlist = playlist("./home/taskone/stream/playlists/dubstep/playlist.txt")

# Path to backup track if other streams fail
backup = single("./home/taskone/stream/backups/dubstep/Task One - Studio Sessions.mp3")

# Do not monitor for radio silence and also specify the expected play order
radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false,[live, playlist, backup])

# Function to manually change song title
title = insert_metadata(radio)
insert = fst(title)
radio = snd(title)  

def set_meta(~protocol,~data,~headers,uri) =
title = url.split(uri)
meta = metadata.export(snd(title))
show_title = meta["title"]

ret = if meta != [] then insert(meta) "Title Updated - #{show_title}" else "No metadata to add!" end
http_response(protocol=protocol,code=200,headers=[("Content-Type","text/html")],data="<html><body><b>#{ret}</b></body></html>") end

# Port to register metadata updates via http
harbor.http.register(port=8080,method="GET","/setmeta",set_meta)


# dump live_dj recordings to a file
timestamp = '%d-%m-%Y'
show_title = 'XXXXXXX'
output.file(%mp3(bitrate=320, id3v2=true), reopen_on_metadata=false, "/var/www/html/recorded_shows/#{show_title} Recorded On #{timestamp}.mp3", live, fallible=true)

# Output to an Icecast Server
output.icecast(
  %mp3(bitrate=192),
  mount="/stream",
  host="localhost", port=8000, password="XXXXXXXX",
  radio)
```

Answer (score 1):

just asked myself the same question configuring a similar solution.
In my case I chose the easy (only?) way. Adding time to the file name so there is no conflict in case of multiple live sessions on the same day (20170323143928)

```
timestamp = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the parameter `append=true` to `output.file`, the new audio data will be appended to existing file instead of overwriting it.

You can combine this with timestamps in the filename to create daily/hourly dumps.

Read the documentation for `output.file` for more parameters: [Liquidsoap 1.4.1 - API Reference: output.file](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.4.1/reference.html#output.file)

Answer (score 0):

Writing `reopen_on_metadata=false` explicitly is not necessary because `reopen_on_metadata` defaults to `false`.

To catch up the recording after a short disconnection, set `append=true`. You need at least this.

The bottom problem is, **to create different files with `output.file` you need to have Liquidsoap re-open the file**: the day after, it's another file. Re-opening is currently what happens when you restart liquidsoap, but obviously it's not the best option.

Instead, add `reopen_when = {00h00}` to `output.file` - it's true everyday at midnight. It's simple, and will not create a file if `live` is off (because in that case it does not try to write at all). Pick another time if you might be streaming at midnight.